# How to do a double select statement in one query SQL

Tags: php, sql

It is possible to do a double select statement into one query, and this show each value individually, using `sum` and `suma` for the first select I'm expecting only one value, and for the second one 4 values.

```
echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowsm['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>'; 
$query = "SELECT SUM(a.totalpoints) as sum
          FROM total as a
          WHERE a.id = '$id'
          GROUP BY a.id
          UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(s.points) as suma
       FROM points as s 
       GROUP BY s.id
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
A 21 first select
A 11 second select
A 10 second select
A 9 second select
A 14 second select
```

21 Total sum

```
A 11 points
A 10 points
A 9 points
A 14 points
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik That if I try to display 'suma' which is the second select  gives me an error

Comment: Could you clarify the result you are trying to get using the values of the example above? Do you mean you want the query to return one record with 5 fields with value 21, 11, 10, 9 and 14?

Comment: What do you mean by "try to display"? What error?

Comment: @Mureinik if I user this echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowsm['suma'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';  says Undefined index: suma

Answer (score 1):

In UNION ALL, the corresponding fields need to have the same name, otherwise how will the system decide which name to display in the column header? Your SQL needs to be of the form:

```
SELECT SUM(a.totalpoints) as suma
      FROM total as a
      WHERE a.id = '$id'
      GROUP BY a.id
      UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(s.points) as suma
   FROM points as s 
   GROUP BY s.id
```

Also, sum is a keyword, so you can not use an alias named sum. i.e. "as sum" is probably not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call more than one select statement in one query unless it's a transaction.
Change your query to this:

```
$query = "
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT SUM(a.totalpoints) as suma
              FROM total as a
              WHERE a.id = '$id'
              GROUP BY a.id
              UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(s.points) as suma
           FROM points as s 
           GROUP BY s.id
    COMMIT;";
```

Also as @Swagata mentioned you cannot use keyword as an alias

Comment: so this means that theres no way to display fits the total points, and then the points

Comment: @JanLeon You either have to run the queries independently, use transaction or use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

`mysql_multi_query()` will run the sql script in a while loop and on each iteration of it return the result of a SELECT statement.